# Showing null values as Zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, morris.js

I'm doing a chart with Morris js.
I get a list of dates and values from the server.
But some of the dates do not exist, I want to show the non-existent dates with the value 0.

For example:
if this is my list of data:

```
data: [
{ year: '2008', value: 20 },
{ year: '2009', value: 10 },
{ year: '2012', value: 50 }
```

I get a chart that goes straight from 2009 to 2012, and cannot see the values for 2010 and 2011 (that should be 0).
[image]

and I need it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: can you please show us the code you used to create the faulty chart? your `data` does not contain information for 2010, 2011, ... what about creating entries for these years (with `value: 0`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code, if `data` is sorted by year:

```
var result = [];
var previous = null;
for (var i in data) {
    var item = data[i];
    if (previous != null)
        for (var year = previous + 1; year < parseInt(item.year); year++)
            result.push({year: new String(year), value: 0});
    result.push(item);
    previous = parseInt(item.year);
}
```

We traverse the data, and from the previous year until the current year (excluding), we add the zero entries. Then we add the current item.

Json result:

```
[
   {"year":"2008","value":20},
   {"year":"2009","value":10},
   {"year":"2010","value":0},
   {"year":"2011","value":0},
   {"year":"2012","value":50}
]
```

Comment: umm, I was hoping I could avoid creating the extra data. this code seems good though.
Thank you

Comment: How about showing the value until today or this year?